# Как понимать союз и(или)?

Tags: союзы, терминология, смысл

Прошу пояснить, как понимать следующий текст с союзом и(или).

> Для получения льготы на проезд требуется предоставить справку с
>   "информацией о членстве пенсионера-садовода в СНТ (о ведении им
>   садоводства и(или) дачного хозяйства в индивидуальном порядке на
>   территории такого объединения)".

Что означает фраза "...и(или)...в индивидуальном порядке..."? Означает ли она, что это относится и к пенсионерам-садоводам, входящим в СНТ, и к тем из них, кто не является членом СНТ и ведет дачное хозяйство индивидуально, не входя в СНТ? Никаких других подробностей не имеется.

Comment: Льгота предоставляется членам СНТ. Подробности не важны.

Comment: @shampar Похоже, Вы поторопились с выводами (см. мой ответ и особенно комментарии к нему).

Comment: Вопрос: это относится... к тем из них, кто не является членом? Нет. Предоставить /надо/ справку с "информацией о членстве.

Answer (score 1):

В описании справки:

> Информация о членстве пенсионера-садовода в СНТ (о ведении им
>   садоводства и(или) дачного хозяйства в индивидуальном порядке на
>   территории такого объединения)

Текст в скобках "(о ведении ...)" является уточнением того, что понимается под "информацией о членстве в СНТ". Выражение **и(или)** использовано с целью сократить перечисление трёх возможных случаев.

Подытожим.
Для получения льготы пенсионер должен предоставить справку о том, что он является членом СНТ и при этом выполнен один из следующих пунктов:
а) либо пенсионер занимается садоводством в индивидуальном порядке на территории СНТ;
б) либо пенсионер ведёт дачное хозяйство в индивидуальном порядке на территории СНТ;
в) либо выполнены оба предыдущих пункта (пенсионер и ведёт дачное хозяйство, и занимается садоводством).

Answer (score 1):

Фраза "в индивидуальном порядке" относится к случаю ведения пенсионером индивидуального хозяйства на территории садоводства, на которое при повторном упоминании в предложении косвенно сослались как на "такое объединение" (индивидуальных хозяйств). При этом предлагается представить справку либо о членстве в садоводстве, либо о ведении садоводства, а если фактически имеет место и то, и другое, то обе справки.

Если оценивать качество текста, то в некоторых руководствах употребление комбинированных предлогов **и/или** считается *недопустимым* для юридически значимых текстов, - эта рекомендация явно нарушена и допускает разные толкования: кто-то примет одну справку (по простой логике достаточно любой из двух), а кто-то переспросит и потребует две (на всякий случай - просто потому, что написанное можно понять как право требовать обе, если они могут быть где-то выданы при наличии к тому оснований).

Answer (score 0):

Бюрократическая пропасть поистине бездонна, и падать в нее можно бесконечно. Вроде бы в скобках дано пояснение, а на деле в скобках и за скобками написаны разные вещи. Член СНТ (садоводческого некоммерческого товарищества) обязан "освоить в течение трех лет земельный участок, рационально и эффективно использовать его для выращивания фруктов, ягод, овощей и другой сельскохозяйственной продукции." (Из примерного устава СНТ). То есть "ведение им садоводства" - обязательное условие. Откуда же взялось ИЛИ? Дачное хозяйство — другая сфера. Для желающих вести дачное хозяйство создаются ДНП (дачные некоммерческие партнерства), там садоводство не обязательно.

Comment: Я только сейчас понял, что имеется в виду (благодаря Вашему ответу). Скорее всего, имеется в виду следующее: льготы предоставляются пенсионерам, которые либо (а) являются членами СНТ, либо (б) занимаются садоводством в индивидуальном порядке на территории СНТ, либо (в) ведут дачное хозяйство в индивидуальном порядке на территории СНТ. "В индивидуальном порядке" означает, что они не являются членами СНТ — это термин такой. Но как же коряво написано! Все наши ответы пока мимо, я думаю. И здесь мы не сможем помочь.

Comment: @grizzly Истину глаголите! Вот здесь нашел об этом: сhttp://www.rossadovod.ru/conference/forum4/topic826/. Можно выйти из СНТ и вести садоводство, огородничество или дачное хозяйство **в индивидуальном порядке** на его территории. Таким образом, в скобках — не пояснение, а другой статус. А скобки, вероятно, означают, что с точки зрения льгот на проезд второй статус не отличается от первого. Нас на этом сайте должен заинтересовать вопрос, корректно ли использование скобок в такой роли.